# Error 403: Response too large when running BigQuery sync queries on Python library

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am running a simple `SELECT` syncronous query in Google BigQuery using the Python client library. I am getting  the following error:

`*** google.cloud.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true`

I am using [run_sync_query()](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery/client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.run_sync_query) for the purpose.

The way I'm doing it is (stripping away unnecesary stuff):

```
def run_query(query_str):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    client = biquery.Client()
    query = client.run_sync_query(query_str)
    query.run()
    return query.fetch_data()
```

I am aware there is a parameter `allowLargeResults` in the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query) but i don't know how to set that parameter from the  client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it like so:

`query.allow_large_results = True`

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/e716fbef3dc74e8853346426af356bad364f6637/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L1090

However, if you set `allow_large_results` then you must also specify a destination table to write the results to:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.allowLargeResults

> [Optional] If true and query uses legacy SQL dialect, allows the query
>   to produce arbitrarily large result tables at a slight cost in
>   performance. Requires destinationTable to be set. For standard SQL
>   queries, this flag is ignored and large results are always allowed.
>   However, you must still set destinationTable when result size exceeds
>   the allowed maximum response size.

Comment: How is the destination table specifically set in the Python library?

Comment: This stuff is pretty easy to Google yourself, but here you go: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#querying-data-asynchronous

Comment: This is actually not using a a sync query, but `run_async_query()` call, which is what I ended up using.

It was not the preferred option because in this case you have to handle the naming of the jobs and destination tables. I was trying to configure it the sync job but AFAIK it is not possible. 

As you can see it wasn't a matter of knowing how to Google :)

Comment: All queries run async on BigQuery. The only difference is if you want to wait for them to complete or not in your client code (blocking -vs- non-blocking). You can set the destination table on both. So, I don't really get what you mean :-/

Comment: Just as quick reference, here is the list of job config parameters which may come in handy: https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig