# How to import a large bigquery table into jupyter lab?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

In Big Query, I have a table with 608 GB of data, 50 million rows, and 2651 columns. I'm trying to load it into Jupyter Lab as a pandas dataframe before doing any modeling. I'm saving the query's results into a pandas dataframe as a destination using %%bigquery. However, because of the big size, I'm getting an error. I followed the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages) and a couple of stackoverflow discussions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523856/error-403-response-too-large-when-running-bigquery-sync-queries-on-python-libra)) that suggested using LIMIT and setting `query.allow large results = True`. However, I am unable to determine how I can apply them to my specific problem.

Kindly please advise.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd be tempted to suggest that we look at the overall goal rather than this technical approach.  What do you plan on "doing" with the data once it is in Jupyter?  Can you perhaps do your processing "in" BigQuery itself rather than exporting it from BigQuery and then processing?

Comment: I worked for a few hours and chipped a few hundred more columns. Even after that, there were pull errors due to the large amount of data. But I've found a solution.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `configuration.query.allowLargeResults` and set it to true, you should add a destination table object.

Set `allowLargeResults` to true in your job configuration.

If you are using python, you can see this example using `allow_large_results` and set it to true.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
 
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()
 
# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the destination table.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"
 
# Set the destination table and use_legacy_sql to True to use
# legacy SQL syntax.
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    allow_large_results=True, destination=table_id, use_legacy_sql=True
)
 
sql = """
    SELECT corpus
    FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare]
    GROUP BY corpus;
"""
 
# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
query_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
 
print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

If you are querying via API

```
"configuration": { "query": { "allowLargeResults": true, "query": "select uid from [project:dataset.table]" "destinationTable": [project:dataset.table] } }
```

Using `allow_large_results` has  limitations. These are the limitations:

- You must specify a destination table.
- You cannot specify a top-level ORDER BY, TOP, or LIMIT clause.
- Window functions can return large query results only if used in
  conjunction with a PARTITION BY clause.

You can see this official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_large_results_using_legacy_sql).

Comment: Thanks Raul for your input. Instead of going through setting `allow_large_results`. I actually fragmented my original 608 GB dataset into 5000 files in GCS bucket using the official documentation here .https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data. Then, loading each of these 5000 files one by one and doing my work. This was my workaround.

Comment: @PiyushVerma As a best practice in Stack Overflow, we are supposed to say "Thank you" by [upvoting good or useful answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment).